# One bad exam that might influence my chances later on

Tags: phd, exams

I'm currently a master's student in a 2-year European program in Theoretical Physics at a top 20 university worldwide. I got back my first grades set. I am very encouraged by my results, but at the same time, I am disappointed in one particular result. I managed to get almost a perfect score in 3 out of 4 subjects, and in the QFT course, I messed up the last exercise, which led to a relatively bad result (just above the class average). I have a relatively good relationship with the professor, as during the semester, I was able to showcase my understanding on a few occasions. I would like to continue with a PhD in theoretical physics. I know that that is the start of the road, and I have to work day and night to prove myself and what I am capable of. But at the same time I see this result as a big stain. Is that going to impact my chances for a PhD?

Sorry for bothering the community, and if you consider this question irrelevant, I'll delete it. Let me know.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-are-ph-d-applications-evaluated-in-the-us-particularly-for-weak-or-borderl Does this answer your question? (In particular the section about GPA)

Comment: @Allure Thank you very much. It does, with respect to the US, but still, Europe is my first choice, to be honest.

Comment: What is the effect on the course grade as a whole?

Comment: @Buffy. So I mean like instead of having a top 5% average now it s more like top 15%

Answer (score 4):

If you apply for a doctorate in a place where application is to an individual PI, then it is their judgement about what "counts" and what doesn't. Therefore, predictions in such places are difficult to make Normally exam grades aren't visible outside the institution that administers them, only overall course grades are.

If you apply in a place that relies on committee decisions, then the criteria are probably broad, much more than GPA. In some places letters of recommendation from people you have worked with are especially important.

It is also generally recognized that people make mistakes, especially in stressful situations where time is a factor. You are expected to be (very) good, but not, likely, perfect. Everyone has bad days. Other people recognize that.

I would guess that this isn't a particular worry anywhere.

That said, if you are aiming at only top institutions, the competition from other (very) good students is fierce.

FWIW, some people who are perfect up to a point find that moving beyond their "natural" ability is very hard. Some fail because they haven't ever had to study and work hard, so never did. Perfection can be worrisome, actually.